# Express.js router require directly or inside a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a express.js performance question. I have my `server.js` where all the routes are defined and the child routes are imported like so:

```
const ROUTE__FOO = require('./routes/foo')
const ROUTE__BAR = require('./routes/bar')

app.use('/api/foo', ROUTE__FOO)
app.use('/api/bar', ROUTE__BAR)
```

So my question is: Is it better / faster to first require the routes inside a variable and then assign this variable to the express.js `app.use` function? Or can I also do this:

```
app.use('/api/foo', require('./routes/foo'))
app.use('/api/bar', require('./routes/bar'))
```

Would there be any problems? I tried to find out what's better, but I couldn't get anything out for this specific problem.

Comment: it's the same, makes not difference. Everything will be loaded at start-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference. For readability it's probably better to put the `require`s at the top of the file, but performance wise it is the same.